# Selling a copy of the original as original is called "fraud" (idiomatic?)

Tags: indefinite-article

> Selling a copy of the original as original is called "fraud"

idiomatic or do we need the indefinite article "a" before fraud like "a fraud"?

Comment: *Forgery* might work (e.g. [Art forgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_forgery))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It don't think *fraud* needs "a". But I think I would turn the second *original* into a noun: *as the original* or *as an original*.

Comment: I'd simplify it further: "Selling a copy as an original is called fraud." The original is redundant.

Comment: I agree. That's more to the point.